# Jump to Cell Based on Value in Another Cell (Macro LibreOffice VBA)

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I want to be able to jump to a cell based on the user entering a date (in B14). 
In column F, I have a list of dates (starting at row 8).
So far, I have `=MATCH(B14,F8:F373)+7` (in B15) which calculates which row the right date is in, and returns a number.

I need to write a macro in LibreOffice VBA that will select the cell in that row, in column G. So far, I have:

```
sub jump

dim document as object
dim dispatcher as object
document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

Doc = ThisComponent
Sheets=Doc.Sheets
sheet=Sheets.getByName("ThisYear")

dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

thisrow =sheet.getCellByPosition(15,2).getValue()

args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args1(0).Value = (G,thisrow)

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())

end sub
```

But it doesn't accept the value being in the form (column, row). I have seen before I need something like   `args1(0).Value = "G15"` but how can I include the variable? (I have tried using 7 instead of G but this doesn't help.)

I have mentioned the sheet name, `sheet=Sheets.getByName("ThisYear")`, but it is all within the one sheet so ideally I wouldn't want to specify this so I could use the macro in different sheets.

I am new to VBA so please reply with the whole sub.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are having trouble figuring out how to change the cell selection in LibreOffice Calc.  Here is a code snippet that shows you how.   In short, you identify a targeted range (`oRange`) (which below is a single cell at location `3,3`), and then pass that object to the `.select()` method.

```
Sub ChangeSelection
  oSheets = ThisComponent.Sheets
  oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
  oRange = oSheet.getCellByPosition(3,3)
  ThisComponent.CurrentController.select(oRange)

End Sub
```

LibreOffice uses uses the UNO API documented [here](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1view_1_1XSelectionSupplier.html#abdae967311a600a66b049e4a2bd5d868).  If you want to browse the properties and methods for an object, use `MsgBox oObject.DBG_properties` or `.DBG_methods`, you usually will be able to find the right thing eventually.  The code snippet in your question returns an error that I could not immediately figure out.